# Name of ui element flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I would like to know the name of the ui element which I want to create.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfplL.png)

There is a map on which points are marked, below it is a "mysterious ui element".
It is necessary that when you swipe the "mysterious ui element" to the right, i + 1 points are indicated on the map.

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlkky.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [scroll_snap_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_snap_list) package. It lets you create a snapping ListView that you can also give a function to execute whenever the user scrolls to a new item. In this function you then need to implement the updating of the UI.